# How do I know the position of selected item in spinner?

Tags: android

I am inflating `Spinner` along with that I am also `inflating` some other `views`

```
LinearLayout child_linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.child_linear);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_custome_layout, child_linear, false);
name = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.name);
price = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.add_price);
names_spinner = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.product_addmore_spinner);
child_linear.addView(myView);
```

Now I getting data for the `spinner`. The question if there are 'n' no.of  spinners how do I know which spinner item user selected?

```
names_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select Toppings")) {
//Show PopUp or Alerts
Toast.makeText(ProductView.this, "position" + names_spinner.getItemIdAtPosition
(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    }
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
});
```

Even when I click on particular spinner item position is also not showing in `Toast`. What's my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing toast only when user click on Select Toppings. Take a look to your code:

```
if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select Toppings")) {
```

Change this line for

```
if (!parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select Toppings")) {
```

And alerts should be shown.

Additionally to know which item is clicked, the listener provided you the clicked position, you can search in you items array this position and you can know which item is.

EDIT:

Now, lets suppose you have more than one spinner. spinner1 and spinner2, for example. You could register an `OnItemSelectedListener` for each one.

Then you can create a global variable called `Spinner clickedSpinner` and inside the `OnItemSelectedListener` of the spinner1 you set the clickedSpinner to spinner1 and inside the `OnItemSelectedListener` of the spinner2 set the clickedSpinner to spinner2:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      clickedSpinner = spinner1;
      ... // Do your stuff here
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

  }
});
```

And:

```
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      clickedSpinner = spinner2;
      ... // Do your stuff here
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

  }
});
```

So, after clicking any item of any `Spinner` you can now know which `Spinner` was clicked because is stored in `clickedSpinner`.

Please note that this variable is not mandatory, you could achieve the same behavior without this global variable, because in each `OnItemSelectedListener` you know which spinner is the clicked. So, you could do the following:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     int spinner1Position = spinner1.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
      ... // Do your stuff here
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

  }
});
```

And:

```
spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      int spinner2Position = spinner2.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
      ... // Do your stuff here
  }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

  }
});
```

Without using a global variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you  that helped me to get the position

Comment: How do I know which spinner I am clicked if there are 'n' no.of spinners?

Comment: @john I've just edited the answer because I thought the explanation would be better using blocks of code. Please let me know if this helps you and if was that you need.

Answer (score 0):

*Try this*

```
 final Spinner names_spinner = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.product_addmore_spinner);

ArrayAdapter<String> madapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yourarray));
madapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

names_spinner.setAdapter(madapter);


names_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

           String mySpinner = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

        Log.i("names_spinner",mySpinner);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
}
```

Comment: Your answer not related to the question. Please read the question.